# clr project using processes

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm stuck for too many days on a problem.

Till now we used xp_cmdshell in over 40 stored procedures. Now we want to replace this calls by using assemblies.
I create an CLR project. It looks like :

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlTypes;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Server;

namespace CmdShellBridge
{
    public class CmdShell
    {
        [SqlProcedure]
        public static void CmdShellBridgeBCP(string arguments, out String ReturnMessage)
        {
            processCMD("cmd.exe", arguments, out ReturnMessage);
        }

        [SqlProcedure]
        public static void CmdShellBridgeMD(string arguments, out String ReturnMessage)
        {
            processCMD("cmd.exe", arguments, out ReturnMessage);
        }

        [SqlProcedure]
        public static void CmdShellBridgeMKDIR(string arguments, out String ReturnMessage)
        {
            processCMD("cmd.exe", arguments, out ReturnMessage);
        }

        [SqlProcedure]
        public static void CmdShellBridgeBCMSyncImport(string arguments, out String ReturnMessage)
        {
            processNotCMD("F:\\ThirdParty_Applications\\BCMSync\\BCMSyncImp.exe", arguments, out ReturnMessage);
        }

        [SqlProcedure]
        public static void CmdShellBridgeBCMSyncExport(string arguments, out String ReturnMessage)
        {
            processNotCMD("F:\\ThirdParty_Applications\\BCMSync\\BCMSyncExp.exe", arguments, out ReturnMessage);
        }

        [SqlProcedure]
        public static void CmdShellBridgeOSQL(string arguments, out String ReturnMessage)
        {
            processCMD("cmd.exe", arguments, out ReturnMessage);
        }

        [SqlProcedure]
        public static void CmdShellBridgeSQLCMD(string arguments, out String ReturnMessage)
        {
            processCMD("cmd.exe", arguments, out ReturnMessage);
        }

        [SqlProcedure]
        public static void CmdShellBridgeDIR(string arguments, out String ReturnMessage)
        {
            processCMD("cmd.exe", arguments, out ReturnMessage);
        }

        [SqlProcedure]
        public static void CmdShellBridgeXCOPY(string arguments, out String ReturnMessage)
        {
            processCMD("cmd.exe", arguments, out ReturnMessage);
        }

        [SqlProcedure]
        public static void CmdShellBridgeDEL(string arguments, out String ReturnMessage)
        {
            processCMD("cmd.exe", arguments, out ReturnMessage);
        }

        [SqlProcedure]
        public static void CmdShellBridgeNETUSE(string arguments, out String ReturnMessage)
        {
            processCMD("cmd.exe", arguments, out ReturnMessage);
        }

        [SqlProcedure]
        public static void CmdShellBridgeMOVE(string arguments, out String ReturnMessage)
        {
            processCMD("cmd.exe", arguments, out ReturnMessage);
        }

        [SqlProcedure]
        public static void CmdShellBridgeCOPY(string arguments, out String ReturnMessage)
        {
            processCMD("cmd.exe", arguments, out ReturnMessage);
        }

        [SqlProcedure]
        public static void CmdShellBridgeBLAT(string arguments, out String ReturnMessage)
        {
            processNotCMD("D:\\EMailer\\blat.exe", arguments, out ReturnMessage);
        }

        [SqlProcedure]
        public static void CmdShellBridgeROBOCOPY(string arguments, out String ReturnMessage)
        {
            processNotCMD("ROBOCOPY", arguments, out ReturnMessage);
        }

        [SqlProcedure]
        public static void CmdShellBridgeRD(string arguments, out String ReturnMessage)
        {
            processCMD("cmd.exe", arguments, out ReturnMessage);
        }

        private static void processCMD(string fileName, string arguments, out String ReturnMessage)
        {
            try
            {
                Process proc = new Process();
                proc.StartInfo.FileName = fileName;
                proc.StartInfo.Arguments = arguments;
                proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
                proc.Start();
                proc.WaitForExit();
                ReturnMessage = "OK";
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ReturnMessage = ex.Message;
            }

        }

        private static void processNotCMD(string fileName, string arguments, out String ReturnMessage)
        {
            try
            {
                Process proc = new Process();
                proc.StartInfo.FileName = fileName;
                proc.StartInfo.Arguments = arguments;
                proc.Start();
                proc.WaitForExit();
                ReturnMessage = "OK";
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ReturnMessage = ex.Message;
            }

        }

    }
}
```

And in stored procedure we use this procedures like in this case:

```
set     @execcommand = ' \c bcp ' + @CSSdbname+'.BankCardtrxGPEtemp in '+@importdir + @Kfilename +' -c -S'+@CSSserver+' -r \n -T -C 1250 -e '+@importdir+'bcp.error -m 1000 >NUL'

declare @sResult nvarchar(max)

exec    dbo.CmdShellBridgeBCP @execcommand, @sResult OUTPUT
```

If I try to execute this, the result is "OK", but in fact nothing was OK, because the used bcp command doesn't import anything.
The same is the result if I try to use some dos commands, like dir, del, mkdir.
The result is OK, but nothing was executed in fact.

My assemblies permission set is set to Unrestricted.
Maybe the problem is that I have to use network shared folders in my commands ?
When I used mkdir with local folder, it works ok.

But in shared folders I have full permissions.

Comment: Does the SQL Server service account have permissions to the share?  I don't see where you are checking the exit code of the invoked process so it may fail silently.  You might consider implementing the functionality as an external service, perhaps orchestrated through T-SQL with Service Broker (i.e. External Activation).

Comment: Exit Code was 1, so process failed. But my way is totally wrong ? I can't use processes with commands in this way ?

Comment: I suggested an external service instead so that you can better redirect `STDOUT` and `STDERR` for logging and troubleshooting.  You are limited in SQLCLR with regards to threading techniques needed to do this (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandardoutput.aspx).  Does the SQL Server service account have permissions to the share and files (e.g. not a local account)?

Comment: Everyone has full permission to shared folders.